# Were elves inspired from Celtic/Irish mythology or Germanic mythology?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves, folklore

Celtic mythology has the Tuatha Dé Danann, druids, Arthurian legends, Camelot and Summer Isles of the Divine, things associated with wood elves.

Germanic mythology has light elves (Ljósálfar) who although not described much are very similar to how Tolkien depicted his elves and the usual high elves (DnD, Warhammer etc).

Another theory is that the invading Indo-Europeans, the source of the long faced race in Old Europe (full of Cro-Magnons and alpinids) were seen as beautiful elves by the inhabitants.

My question is: From which mythology, and at what time period did the Tolkiensque Elf and the 19th century English fairy tale version of the "elf" (being associated with woods, noble-long lived race, pointy ears, beautiful features etc) come from/solidify?

Comment: Are you asking for the inspiration for Tolkien's Elves specifically? Or elves in general?

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to turn this from one question into much more general exploration of the idea?